# Dynamically append Angular2 components to the dom

Tags: angularjs, angular

I want to be able to click a button in order to add a new component. So for example, if Angular 2 was more like Angular 1 I could do:

```
<button (click)="addComponent()">add</button>
```

ts:

```
addComponent():void { 
    let component =  $compile('<component-selector></component-selector>')(scope)
    ele.append(component)
}
```

note: I know similar questions have been asked a few times on here but the answers I have read have been contradictory and mostly reliant upon deprecated code such as DynamicComponentLoader. I can't find anything relevant on the official docs and ideally want to find a standardised way of doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components)

Answer (score 5):

No. Angular 2 is pretty much as Angular 1, and doing that in Angular 1 has never been the recommended way of manipulating the DOM.

The recommended way is to modify the model, and to use the template to generate HTML from the model:

```
private components = [];

addComponent() {
    this.components.push({}); // this object would typically contain the inputs of the component
}
```

and in the template:

```
<component-selector *ngFor="let c of components"></component-selector>
```